# include semantic images with php if view port is larger than 1024px

Tags: php, html, image, include, semantics

I have been searching for a solution to help improve mobile first responsive websites performance.

The problem:

I need to make SEO friendly inline images for a website. One thing I did was using picturefill.js to serve smaller images for smaller devices.
But... In the design I got from the designer, there is fewer images for mobile(only 3) and 9 for desktop. This means, if they have to be inline and semantic, the small devices will still request the other 6, and that seems to a lot for a slow 3g connection.

So, is there any good way to include images(not as background + display:none) if viewed on a screen larger than normal handheld devices, maybe with php?

Hope this is not considered as "blackhat" seo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by checking the user agent that is making the request.  This is not a fool proof but you could solve the majority of your use cases with it.
Something like this from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Once you know the user agent that is making the request, you can server the appropriate version to that requester.

```
if($type_a){
//do type a stuff
}else{
//do type !a stuff 
}
```

Some edge cases include the wide array of screen sizes with Android.  It is also not true "responsive" and more of an "mdot" way to approach the issue but frankly, so is your design.  True responsive in my opinion would either rely on lazily loading resources based on the view port or serving the same versions relying purely on js, html, and css to solve the issue.

Comment: Many thanks! So to my problem, got any references on the lazily loading or other ways to avoid all those extra requests on mobile that is required for a better user experience on desktop?

Comment: Not really.  By definition, if you're trying to avoid client side checks to the server, you need to push the logic to the server so that the client doesn't have to worry about it.  By doing the above, you create a way that you can branch your server side logic for the two types of clients you're serving a) mobile that is a paired down, optimized set of resources for mobile and b) desktop that is less constrained by bandwidth and resources.

Comment: Okay :) Thanks a lot for your input mate! I don't think I have the skills yet for serving content via a structured backend. Would be nice in the future, because I see some limitation in responsive design on the performance part.